# How can I get knowledge about RAM usage by my webapplication?

Tags: performance-monitoring, memory, .net, memory-usage

I have a .Net web application. On one server there are several instances of this application in different versions. How should I know what amount or RAM maximally can consume one instance? How can I monitor this? What is the save level of free memory in the server?
I have to also add than besides this instances of web application I have also there sql server 2005.

Answer (score 2):

Put each application into its own application pool. This will let you monitor each individual w3wp.exe process.

Answer (score 1):

The more memory that SQL Server has access to the better.  If possible put it on it's own machine so that you can dedicate the memory on the server to SQL, leaving all the memory on the other server to the web applications.

The general rule is buy as much RAM as you can afford.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's windows you can start the performance monitor.

See this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process

Under windows 7 you add a new counter.  Search for Process, and you can select individual processes.

The other thing to look at is Virtual Memory or Swap file usage and disk.
From memory "commit charge" or page faults/sec are useful statistics to look it.

Comment: Right- but first, the applications need to be in individual application pools in IIS, otherwise they're all running in the same PID.